# Formatting JSON files for SQLContext

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm experiencing issues when loading JSON which are dependent on formatting of input JSON file.

According to Spark documentation on JSON Datasets, each line on input file must be a valid JSON Object.  re:

"Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will most often fail."

So, if I have an input JSON file such as:

```
{
"Year": "2013",
"First Name": "DAVID",
"County": "KINGS",
"Sex": "M",
"Count": "272"
},
{
"Year": "2013",
"First Name": "JAYDEN",
"County": "KINGS",
"Sex": "M",
"Count": "268"
}
```

Are there any existing tools or scripts to convert to:

```
{"Year": "2013","First Name": "DAVID","County": "KINGS","Sex": "M","Count":"272"},
{"Year": "2013","First Name": "JAYDEN","County": "KINGS","Sex": "M","Count": "268"}
```

where the JSON conforms to "Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object"

If I format to this style above, things work as expected.  But, I made these mods manually over a few rows.  I cannot do this for entire data set, so looking for an existing script or tool.

OR

I could load to JDBC available database if that's a better option.  Thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply load the JSON files into an RDD first using `sc.wholeTextFiles()` and remove the file name column, then run the `SQLContext` read on the RDD contents.

e.g.

```scala
val jsonRdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("samplefile.json").map(x => x._2)
val jsonDf = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRdd)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, you can run it on multiple files by passing in a wildcard to wholeTextFiles, the rest should work as is.

Answer (score -1):

What if you make it an array by adding square brackets. like this;

```
  [
    {
    "Year": "2013",
    "FName": "DAVID",
    "County": "KINGS",
    "Sex": "M",
    "Count": "272"
    },
    {
    "Year": "2013",
    "FName": "JAYDEN",
    "County": "KINGS",
    "Sex": "M",
    "Count": "268"
    }
    ]
```

If I take your file and add the brackets I can iterate through it with Node.js and output a file that looks like what you want. The caveat in node.js being I cant have variable First Name-- I had to change it to FName.

Comment: This has nothing to do with node. Apache Spark has issues with multiline JSON and OP wanted to know how to solve that issue and make sure Spark accepts valid JSON which is multiline